# Функции и их методы. Переменные класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Если в словаре уже имеется `subscriber` то надо `amount` добавить к уже имеющемуся `value`. Например `Sema` уже есть в словаре с `value` 4000. И я добавил его снова с `value` 3000. Словарь должен вывести 7000.

```
class Provider:
    payments = {}
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.subscribers = ["Chyngyz", "Sema", "Tagay"]

    def register_payment(self, subscriber, amount):
        if subscriber in self.subscribers:
            Provider.payments[subscriber] = amount
        else:
            raise ValueError

n1 = Provider("Megaline")
print(n1.name)
print(n1.subscribers)
n1.register_payment("Chyngyz", 5000)
n1.register_payment("Sema", 4000)
n1.register_payment("Sema", 3000)
print(n1.payments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if subscriber in self.subscribers:
    self.payments[subscriber] = self.payments.get(subscriber, 0) + amount
```

метод `get` словаря возвращает значение по ключу или заданное значение при отсутствии ключа в словаре.

Я конечно не до конца понимаю конечной задачи, но имхо можно сделать так:

```
class Provider:
    payments = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.subscribers = set()

    def register_payment(self, subscriber, amount):
        self.payments[subscriber] = self.payments.get(subscriber, 0) + amount
        self.subscribers.add(subscriber)


n1 = Provider("Megaline")
print(n1.name)
n1.register_payment("Chyngyz", 5000)
n1.register_payment("Sema", 4000)
n1.register_payment("Sema", 3000)
print(n1.subscribers)
print(n1.payments) 

# Megaline
# {'Chyngyz', 'Sema'}
# {'Chyngyz': 5000, 'Sema': 7000}
```

Поскольку `subscribers` по сути является списком ключей `payments`, дабы не плодить сущности можно сделать так:

```
class Provider:
    payments = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def register_payment(self, subscriber, amount):
        self.payments[subscriber] = self.payments.get(subscriber, 0) + amount

    def subscribers(self):
        return list(self.payments.keys())


n1 = Provider("Megaline")
print(n1.name)
n1.register_payment("Chyngyz", 5000)
n1.register_payment("Sema", 4000)
n1.register_payment("Sema", 3000)
print(n1.subscribers())
print(n1.payments)

# Megaline
# ['Chyngyz', 'Sema']
# {'Chyngyz': 5000, 'Sema': 7000}
```

Comment: спасибо. Очень помогли)

Comment: @ChyngyzAkmatov. Незачто. Лучшее спасибо - зеленая галочка рядом с ответом )))

Comment: @ChyngyzAkmatov. Еще вариант добавил